# Remove a range of activities from the stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back

I have an activity A that go to B and then C, then D and then F and after I finish with F I want to jump to B again, but all activities C, D, and F need to be remove from history but still possible to go back from B to A, is there a way I can do this?? thanks!!

Comment: try to understand my logic, make singleton object for the every activity. and then that object used  in activity F. in this Activity F you can finish whatever Activity which you wann finish in between A-F.

Comment: Why don't you use fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could intercept the back button pressed event in Activity F (or another event) and use an `intent` to get back to activity B.

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
    // Do what you need done here 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    // if you need to pass data back to ActivityB
    //intent.putExtra("tagName", yourData);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

Adding the flag as xbadal suggested is on the right idea, but according the Android documentation it seems you need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

From Android documentation:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Depending on which other flags are set at the time of calling the `intent` you may need to check to see which flags are already included by calling `getFlags()` and removing the conflicting ones with `removeFlags(int)`.

Comment: mm but with this only F will be destroyed but C and D will still be in the history stack, how can I remove those two only when I leave F??

Comment: If the other activities need to be destroyed you can call `this.finished();` in the individual activities as you go up the ladder. Without knowing more about you code and the intent of your code I can't really give much more info.

Comment: Are you concerned that when the user gets back to activity B that when they press the back button they will land back to one of the activities between 'F' and 'B'?

Comment: I just checked one of my old projects. I did pretty much the same thing, except I used the `onKeyLongPress` event and when I got back to my intended activity 'B'  the other activities between 'F' and 'B' did not get called when I pressed the back button. The App went to the next activity in activity 'B's history stack eg. activity 'A'.

Comment: I edited my code by adding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`  to the intent using `addFlag(int)`. And added the explanation from the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try this. this will clear all your previous stack and start a new activity

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(F.this, B.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this)
```